# Error: Sqlite Database OnCreate

Tags: android, sqlite

When I use Sqlite Database in android

With code below:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public String test="";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        test="here11";
        // Category table create query
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + " ( "+ KEY_Phone + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_email + " TEXT, " + KEY_Pass + " TEXT, " + KEY_MomNum + " TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I put a test string to check if enter to onCreate function

And In main class :

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), db.test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I show empty toast why??

thank you.

Comment: Did you clear cache / data for the app? Else its not gonna create the database again, and that might be why

Comment: Change getApplicationContext to THIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is created once, so if you run this second time, it won't run the onCreate method again as the database already exists.
What you need to do is increase your database version. This will call `onUpgrade` which will then call `onCreate` again and it will create the database again.

Comment: You should define the constant `DATABASE_VERSION` somewhere, this just needs to be increased.
This is where the constant is used `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);` It is possible just to replace the constant with a number, but just bad practice

Comment: Check your code, its there only : `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);`

Answer (score 0):

You should delete application cache and test again.